# Limit resources in docker-compose v3

Tags: docker-compose

mem_limit is no longer supported in version 3 of docker-compose.yml file. The documentation tells that I should use the `deploy.resources` key instead but also that this part will only be effective with swarm or docker stack.

> cpu_shares, cpu_quota, cpuset, mem_limit, memswap_limit: These have been replaced by the resources key under deploy. Note that deploy configuration only takes effect when using docker stack deploy, and is ignored by docker-compose.

... [as written in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#/version-2x-to-3x).

How do I set memory/cpu limits with docker-compose with v3 format of the yml file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing and found this:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4513

So in short it's just not possible to do that, you have to use the version 2.1 of the docker-compose format to be able to specify limits that are not ignored by `docker-compose up`

Comment: As a result of the issue that you linked, compatibility mode was developed to allow v2  container resource limiting abilities in v3 compose files. The yaml syntax is identical to v2 syntax. See my answer to a similar question in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42457889/limit-useable-host-resources-in-docker-compose-without-swarm/55980801#55980801).

Answer (score 12):

you can try `docker-compose --compatibility up` which is CLI flag that convert v3 files  to their v2 equivalent, with deploy options translated when possible.

Comment: According to a [docker-compose contributor](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4513#issuecomment-368167466), v2.x schema is recommended over v3 if you aren't using Swarm.

Answer (score 6):

I was searching for this issue a while ago. I have found my answer [here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part5/). At first, I tried to implement this functionality without using docker stack, but that did not work.

Here is the piece of code which you would use to limit container's CPU/memory consumption. For additional attributes, you can search the documentation of docker.

```
 deploy:
  replicas: 5
  resources:
    limits: 
      cpus: "0.1"
      memory: 50M
```

Compose file does not recognize deploy attributes, unless you deploy the application as a stack.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the case anymore. According to the new documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#deploy
It states that resources are repspected by docker compose.
I can confirm this now.

Comment: and is ignored by docker-compose up ....