# Limit useable host resources in Docker compose without swarm

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I simply want to limit the resources of some Docker containers in a docker-compose file. The reason is simple: There are multiple apps/services running on the host. So I want to avoid, that a single container can use e.g. all memory, which harms the other containers.

From the docs I learned, that this can be done using `resources`. But this is beyond `deploy`. So I have to write my docker-compose file like the following example:

```
  php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./www:/www
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 512M
```

This gave me the warning:

> WARNING: Some services (php) use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support deploy configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to deploy to a swarm.

And that seems to be true: `docker stats`confirms, the container is able to use all the ram from the host.

The documentation says:

> Specify configuration related to the deployment and running of services. This only takes effect when deploying to a swarm with docker stack deploy, and is ignored by docker-compose up and docker-compose run.

But I don't need clustering. It seems that there is no other way to limit resources using a docker composer file. Why is it not possible to specify some kind of `memory`tag like the start-parameter in `docker run`does?

Example: `docker run --memory=1g $imageName`

This works perfectly for a single container. But I can't use this (at least without violating a clean separation of concerns), since I need to use two different containers.

#### Edit: Temp workaround

I found out, that I'm able to use `mem_limit` directly after downgrading from version 3 to version 2 (placing `version: '2'` on top). But we're currently on version 3.1, so this is not a long-time solution. And the docs say, that `deploy.resources` is the new replacement for v2 tags like `mem_limit`.

Someday, version 2 is deprecated. So resource management isn't possible any more with the latest versions, at least without having a swarm? Seems a worsening for me, can't belive this...

Comment: Similar query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453473/limit-resources-in-docker-compose-v3 . " cpu_shares, cpu_quota, cpuset, mem_limit, memswap_limit: These have been replaced by the resources key under deploy. Note that deploy configuration only takes effect when using docker stack deploy, and is ignored by docker-compose"

Answer (score 30):

Since many Docker Compose users have [complained](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4513) about this incompatibility of compose v3 vs v2, the team has developed [compatibility mode](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5684).

You can retain the same deploy structure that you provided and it will not be ignored, simply by adding the --compatibility flag to the docker-compose command (docker-compose --compatibility up), as explained [here](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-78-using-compatibility-mode-to-set-memory-and-cpu-limits). I tested this with version 3.5 and verified with docker stats and can confirm that it works.

Comment: Yes but no.. My docker container won't start anymore during reboot when using `docker compose --compatibility up`. The documentation isn't really clear, but it seems like need to use services for that (but I don't want swarm).. so uh.. the alternative is process manager?? Or shouldn't I use `restart_policy`? https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#restart-policy-details

Answer (score -2):

You can run the docker daemon in swarm mode on a single host. It will add extra un-needed features like the etcd service discovery but that's all behind the scene.

The Docker documentation has a "note" about it here https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#three-networked-host-machines